# Modifying critical point of function on manifold ODE theory

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Assume $M$ is compact Riemannian manifold and $g(t)$ is a time dependent metric. Assume $\Psi:M\times [0,C)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $C<\infty$. Suppose we have $(\partial_t\Psi -\Delta_{g(t)} \Psi)\geq 0$. If $\Psi\geq 0$ on $M\times 0$, then, $\Psi \geq 0$  everywhere.

Proof is as follows:

It suffices to assume that case $\Psi>0$. Now, assume for contradiction $\Psi<0$ somewhere. Since $M$ is compact, we can find $(x'',t'')$ such that $\Psi(x'',t'')=0$ and $\Psi(x,t)\geq 0$ for all $x\in M$ and all $t\in [0,t'']$. Then on this point, $\partial_t \Psi$ $\leq 0$ and $\Delta \Psi \geq 0$.

I am confsed as to why compactness implies the existence of $(x'',t'')$ as above and why that implies $\partial_t \Psi\leq 0$.

Note.

1. For fixed $x$, there exists $t_x$ such that $\Psi(x,t_x)=0$.
2. For fixed $t$ there exists unique $x_t$ such that $\Psi(x_t,t)\geq  \Psi(x,t)$ for all $x\in M$.
3. There are proofs but using maximal time, I don't understand why such time exists by compactness.

Comment: I think the main idea is to use $1.$ in your Note (which I think follows by the IVT), then compactness, to see that there must be a point $x''$, with $t_{x''}$ smallest possible, for which $\Psi(x'',t_{x''}) = 0$. At this point $\Psi$ achieves a local minimum with respect to the first coordinate, i.e.  keeping $t_{x''}$ fixed and varying only the first coordinate (so that the hessian is positive definite) and is decreasing with respect to time.

Comment: @porridgemathematics Hi. Yes, note 1 follows from IVT. The issue I have is using compactness to prove existence of smallest possible $t_{x''}$. Could you elaborate on that in an anser? Thanks

Comment: I might type up an answer later, but I think the idea is to show that $M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} : x \rightarrow t_{x}$ is continuous using compactness, and then use compactness again to show that this function achieves a minimum on $M$.

Comment: I do not see why your points 1. and 2. are true, but I also do not think they are relevant to the statement you want to show.

Comment: @s.harp For fixed $x$, $\Psi(x,.)$ is continuous with connected domain. For fixed t, $\Psi(.,t)$ is continuous with compact domain.

Comment: Yes, sure, but that does not imply that for any $x$ you have a $t_x$ with $\Psi(x,t_x)=0$. Or that for fixed $t$ the maximiser $x_t$ of $\Psi(x_t,t)$ is unique (just that it exists).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X:=\{t\in [0,C)\mid \exists x: \Psi(t,x)<0\}$, which is an open set and so $t'':=\inf (X)$ is not contained in $X$, in particular you have $\Psi(t, x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in M$ and $t\in[0,t'']$.

Now let $(t_n, x_n)$ be so that $t_n\to t''$ and $\Psi(t_n, x_n)<0$ for all $n$. By compactness of $M$ the sequence $x_n$ can be assumed to be convergent to some $x''$ and then $\Psi(t'',x'')\leq 0$ by continuity of $\Psi$. But we already have $\Psi(t'',x'')\geq0$, so $\Psi(t'',x'')=0$.